# System.Printing.PrintServerException: An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: Access is denied as a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have gone through the similar questions on Stack overflow.But still I am not able to fix my problem
I am trying to access network shared printer through my windows service written in c#.
When I run through development environment,it is working fine.
But after  creating a installer and run like it as a background service that time I am getting error like below
**

> "System.Printing.PrintServerException: An exception occurred while
>   creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: Access is denied"

**

Here I have given my code

```
using (PrintServer networkPrintServer = new   PrintServer(networkPrinterServer))
                {
                    using (PrintQueue networkPrintQueue = new PrintQueue(networkPrintServer, networkPrinterName,PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter
                          ))
                    {
                        PrintSystemJobInfo printJob = networkPrintQueue.AddJob(networkPrinterName);
                        networkPrintQueue.Refresh();
                        printJob.Refresh();
                        printJob.JobStream.Write(bytesToPrint, 0, bytesToPrint.Length);
                        printJob.JobStream.Close();
                        return PrinterSuccessfullyCompletedPrintJob;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run your service from any windows Administrator account role.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Maxym.You have saved my time..It is working fine now